# Source Not Available for Crystal report on visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I'm developing a windows application with c#. I want to generate a report with data which i stored in MySQL database. I used SAP crystal report to generate it. but after clicking generate button (button used for generating a report) there is an error occurred.

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQgqS.png)

my code

```
private void btnGen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show second form called as Report
        Report rpt = new Report();
        rpt.Show();
    }
```

this is Report Form

```
public void GenerateReport()
    {

        try
        {

            db_connection();
            string q4 = "select * from detail";
            mcd = new MySqlCommand(q4, connect);
            mcd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataSet1 d1 = new DataSet1();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(mcd);
            sda.Fill(d1.detail);
            CrystalReport1 crpt = new CrystalReport1();
            crpt.SetDataSource(d1);
            CristalRptViewr.ReportSource = crpt;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
```

here detail is my database table
please help me...
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be saying that You have a missing component named as crdb_adoplus.dll in the dotnet1 directory. You should make a directory in the said folder and then add the said .dll component in that directory. You can download that component from net and then add following in your config file:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Then before building your project delete the bin and obj folders and then rebuild your project. Hope it solves the problem.

If the problem still don't solve then try to delete all your crystal assemblies and reinstall the crystal environement for .NET

Comment: This is included in the config file. Also i reinstalled the crystal report. but it's not solved. plz can u help??

Comment: have u yourself made a dotnet1 directory and add a crdb_adoplus.dll file in that directory?

Comment: what's the name of directory i should create and where??

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86 in this directory check whether there is dotnet1 named directory is.. and it should have crdb_adoplus.dll file

Comment: it has a folder called dotnet. not dotnet1. are they same? my crytal report version is 13.0.12.1494

Comment: add a dotnet1 diorectory.. and then delete your bin and obj folders and then recuild your project

Answer (score 1):

Add these line in App.config file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
      <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
      </startup>
   </configuration>
```

Comment: This also already include in configuration file.but it is not sloved :(